# Partial matches using mongo's primitive package

Tags: regex, mongodb, go, mongo-go

I am using Mongo's `Primitive` package to get a bson value based on what was submitted. This is what I am currently doing

```
school = "Havard"
value = primitive.Regex{Pattern: school, Options: ""}
```

This will only match bson values that are `Havard`, how do I make this regex case insensitive and make it match for example, `hava`

In all, if I use `hava` for a search, I should also get `Havard`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `primitive.Regex{Pattern: school}` matches substrings too, but it's not case insensitive. Use the `"i"` option to make it case insensitive:

```
value = primitive.Regex{Pattern: school, Options: "i"}
```

Also note that if the value of `school` contains special regexp characters, that might give you unexpected results or errors. So best is to quote it with e.g. using [`regexp.QuoteMeta()`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#QuoteMeta):

```
value = primitive.Regex{Pattern: regexp.QuoteMeta(school), Options: "i"}
```

Answer (score 1):

For GO users the filter looks like this:

```
filter := bson.D{{"column_name", primitive.Regex{Pattern: school, Options: "i"}}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).